# a column in R dataframe showing up as a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe and this is bit odd.

when I do a class(df$Contributor) it shows that its a dataframe , dataframe whithin a dataframe ?? :(

```
> class(df$Contributor)
[1] "data.frame"
>
```

Is there any way I could change this to a factor ?

Here's a partial output from str(df1)

```
$ ArticleId  : Factor w/ 186 levels "10.1002/ajh.26",..: 167 24 130 136 5 15 20 179 175 70 ...
 $ Volume     : Factor w/ 93 levels "10","100","103",..: NA 12 NA 67 NA NA NA NA NA 18 ...
 $ Issue      : Factor w/ 14 levels "1","10","11",..: NA 11 NA 9 NA NA NA NA NA 8 ...
 $ Members    :'data.frame':    186 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ Contributor: chr  "Ellis Johnson A, Hernandez John , Erin Martin D, Doe Jane M" "Ibrahim Joseph A" "Tenzen E M, Zhao V, Jahn T, Lee S J, McCarthy P L, Izzo J D, Romi M, Drexler R, Dlesch S, Tim H, Atamandi N, Lee E, Persuzo"| __truncated__ "Croso, Tim Zi, Gram Lindsey R, Jackson Samuel J, Friedman Tom A, Johnson Boris J, Johnson Alan "| __truncated__ ...
```

I tried doing

```
df$Contributor <- as.factor(df$Contributor)
```

I got an error

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Comment: `str()` on all of `df` would probably be more informative.

Comment: Did you try changing the class?  `df$Col1 <- as.factor(df$Col1)`?

Comment: @RaphaelK, I updated my question with what you suggested. I got an error while doing that

Comment: @joran thanks for the suggestion i have updated my question based on your feedback

Comment: How did you create such an object in the first place? The "real" error is clearly elsewhere in the code. This would only be fixing the symptom and not the cause.

Comment: @MrFlick you were right on the money Flick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
df$new_col <- as.factor(df$Members$Contributor)
```

and then remove the "bad" column via `df$Members <- NULL`.

You may have accidentally created this problem by doing something like:

```
df$Members <- Members
```

where `Members` was a one column data frame with a column called `Contributor`. For example,

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:5,y = 1:5)
d$z <- data.frame(z1 = letters[1:5])
> d
  x y z1
1 1 1  a
2 2 2  b
3 3 3  c
4 4 4  d
5 5 5  e
> str(d)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ z:'data.frame':  5 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ z1: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: you are 100% right, i did something stupid like that and now I am cleaning up my code from what i did earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The following should also work:

```
d$z <- as.factor(unlist(d$z))
```

At least it did on @joran s example.

This will not work if the data.frame z has more than one column, but you will get an error indicating non-conforming sizes, which is reassuring.